# ¿La mejor estrategia para cargar imagenes en un CollectionView?

Tags: maui

Estoy construyendo una pagina que tiene un CollectionView que carga desde una API un listado de 217 productos aproximadamente. Los datos llegan en json en el cual viene incluida la imagen del producto.
Una vez cargado el CollectionView veo que las imágenes están bien y corresponden con lo que esta en la base de datos, pero al refrescar la pagina comienzan a aparecen las imagenes erroneamente en las Tarjetas que no tienen imagen como se muestra en el video. Si me voy al final de la collectionview y luego subo es peor.

Alguien sabe como resolver el problema.

Estoy cargando directamente del JSON a los items del CollectionView o debo crear las imágenes físicamente en el dispositivo?

Cual es la mejor estrategia para hacer funcionar correctamente el CollectionView?

[Video con funcionamiento](https://youtube.com/shorts/GFRVKOR_NpQ?feature=share)

XAML

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PedidosMovil.Controles"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Farmacia.Common.Models"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PedidosMovil.ViewModels"
         x:Class="PedidosMovil.Views.ProductosPage"
         Title="Lista de Productos">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ToImage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<RefreshView Command = "{Binding ObtenerTodosProductosCommand}"
             RefreshColor="Blue"

             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             IsRefreshing = "{Binding IsBusy}">



    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    x:Name="ListaProductos"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Productos}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
                    RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding DelayLoadMoreCommand}"
                    Margin="10">

        <CollectionView.EmptyView>
            <ContentView>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="Cargando productos"
                           Margin="10,25,10,10"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Label Text="Un momento..."
                           FontAttributes="Italic"
                           FontSize="12"
                           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </CollectionView.EmptyView>

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Kardex">


                <Frame
                    Margin="5"
                    Padding="0"
                    HeightRequest="112"
                    InputTransparent="True"
                    IsClippedToBounds="True"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    Visual="Default"
                    CornerRadius="10">
                    <!-- {Binding Afecto} -->

                    <Grid Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0">
                            <Border.StrokeShape>
                                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="4" />
                            </Border.StrokeShape>
                            <Image
                                Margin="0"
                                Aspect="AspectFit"
                                HeightRequest="100"
                                WidthRequest="100"
                                Source="{Binding ImagenProducto, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}"/>
                        </Border>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="4">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=ComisionVentas, StringFormat='{0:P0}'}"
                                   TextColor="Green"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding IdProducto}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="10"
                                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=PrecioVenta, StringFormat='{0:C0}'}"
                                   FontFamily="Roboto"
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Descripcion}"
                                   FontSize="12"
                                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   FontFamily="Roboto"
                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="3"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Barcode}"
                                   FontFamily="Roboto"
                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                </Frame>



            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</RefreshView>
```

ViewModel

```
    namespace PedidosMovil.ViewModels;

public partial class ProductosViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    readonly IProducto producto = new ProductoServicio();

    private ObservableCollection<Kardex> productos = new ObservableCollection<Kardex>();

    public ObservableCollection<Kardex> Productos
    {
        get => productos;
        private set => productos = value; // SetProperty(ref productos, value);
    }

    public ICommand ListRefreshCommand;

    public ProductosViewModel()
    {
        // ObtenerTodosProductos();
        ListRefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
            if (!IsBusy)
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                try
                {
                    await ObtenerTodosProductos();
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    [ICommand]
    public async Task ObtenerTodosProductos()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Productos.Clear();
            var prod = await GenericRestClient.GetAll<Kardex>();
            if (prod.Success)
            {
                var oproductos = prod.Data.ToObservableCollection<Kardex>();
                oproductos.ToList().ForEach(x => productos.Add(x));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }

    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable<T> original)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(original);
    }


    async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var producto = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Kardex;
        if (producto == null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ProductosPage)}");

        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(col);
    }
}
```

JSON

```
    "mensaje": "ok",
"response": [
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "00",
        "descripcion": "ARRIENDO DE JUEGOS ELECTRONICOS ",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 0.0000,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "001",
        "descripcion": "PALLETS REFACCIONADOS",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 5000.0000,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "009",
        "descripcion": "CHARQUI SUPER JAMON SERRANO 10 x 20 Grs.",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 6302.5200,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "010",
        "descripcion": "CHARQUI XL 10 x 28 Grs",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 10084.0300,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "011",
        "descripcion": "TOCINETAS 40GR ",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 3109.2400,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "012",
        "descripcion": "PAPAS FRITAS PAPILLON 120GR",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 4201.6800,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "013",
        "descripcion": "PAPAS FRITAS EL ARRIERO 170GR",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 4033.6100,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "014",
        "descripcion": "TOCINETAS EL ARRIERO 150 GR ",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 3630.2500,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "015",
        "descripcion": "PAPAS FRITAS SUPER 6 X170 GRS ",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 0.0000,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    },
    {
        "idBodega": 1,
        "idProducto": "016",
        "descripcion": "CHARQUI  20 X 4 GRS ",
        "idUM": "001",
        "imagenProducto": "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",
        "barcode": "",
        "comisionVentas": 0.0300,
        "productoLiquido": false,
        "aplicaEstadistica": true,
        "margenBruto": 0.0000,
        "tipoImpuestoAdicional": 0,
        "idClasificacion": 0,
        "stockMinimo": 0.0000,
        "stockMaximo": 0.0000,
        "stockTotal": 0.0000,
        "precioCosto": 0.0000,
        "precioVenta": 1260.5000,
        "usuario": "userdef"
    }
]
```

}